# DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate, popstate

I am adding the functionality to move back or forward to a previous page. I implemented the popState and PushState, but I'm getting this error;

**DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' and URL 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html#'**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="'wrap">
  
<button class = B1 id="users">View users</button>

<input type="search" id="input" placeholder="Search a user">

</div>
<div id="results"></div>


</div>

<script> 
const renderResult = (i, v) => {
const pre_id = document.createElement("pre");
const dt_id = document.createElement("dt");
dt_id.textContent = i;
pre_id.appendChild(dt_id);
if (v !== "undefined") {
  const dd_id = document.createElement("dd");
  const dd_text = document.createElement("dd");


    dd_id.textContent = v;

  pre_id.appendChild(dd_id);
}

return pre_id;
};

const formatUser = (obj, level) => {
const dl = document.createElement("dl");

let padString = "";

for (let k = 0; k < level; k++) {
  padString += "  ";
}

for (let k in obj) {
  if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
    dl.appendChild(renderResult(k));

    console.log(padString + k + ":");

    if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
      obj[k].forEach((element) => {
        if (typeof element === "object") {
          dl.appendChild(formatUser(element, level + 1));
        } else {
          dl.appendChild(renderResult(element));
          console.log(padString + element);
        }
      });
    } else {
      dl.appendChild(formatUser(obj[k], level + 1));
    }
  } else {
    dl.appendChild(renderResult(k, obj[k]));
  }
}

return dl;
};

const results = document.getElementById("results");

function getUsers(url) {
results.innerHTML = "";

fetch(url)
  .then((res) => (res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res)))
  .then((data) => {

    results.innerHTML = "";

    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      data.forEach((item) => {
        results.append(
          formatUser(item, 0),
        );
      });
    } else {
      results.append(formatUser(data));
    }

    // push the new result into the browser's history
    history.pushState({ result: data }, '', url);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
}

// detect when the user goes back and retrieve the previous result
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
 if (event.state && event.state.result) {
   // render the previous result
   results.innerHTML = "";
   if (Array.isArray(event.state.result)) {
     event.state.result.forEach((item) => {
       results.append(
         formatUser(item, 0),
       );
     });
   } else {
     results.append(formatUser(event.state.result));
   }
 }
});

const users = document.getElementById("users");
users.addEventListener(
"onclick",
getUsers(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/`)
);

const input = document.getElementById("input");

input.addEventListener("change", (event) =>
getUsers(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${event.target.value}`)
);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```